# react native : image is uploading using expo-image-picker but not uploading using react-native-image-picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-image-picker

I have tried uploading images to node js server, It is working fine with expo-image-picker but it is not working in react-native-image-picker

by doing this I noticed that the URI between expo and react-native CLI is different

by using expo-image-picker the URI is

```
  "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540satya89310%252Fembteen/ImagePicker/a05bf1a7-cef8-4cef-b73d-8fc330007927.jpg",
```

this is working fine and the image is uploading on node js server

but by react-native-image-picker the URI is

```
"uri": "content://com.embteen.provider/root/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/images/image-12b4f263-5747-4404-a41e-1acf8926ea24.jpg"
```

Which is not uploading the image.

What did I miss ?

Comment: Please help me how to do that ?

Comment: The only thing I can tell you is that expo-image-picker works like a charm and react-native-image-picker is just bad I cant even get it running because it only throws errors.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `react-native-image-picker` on android, you should use `response.path` instead `response.uri` to get the actual file path. [check out docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/master/docs/Reference.md)

Don't forget to add `file:///` to the beginning of `response.path` you get from android.

`response.uri` is not a persistent path and can't rely on it when uploading.

Comment: Add file:/// is works for me. Thanks @mcnk.